# How does two weapon fighting calculate the offhand attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization

I am making a character who uses two weapons at once, but this is the first time that I have attempted to make a dual-wielding character. He will have 2 attacks/round from his BAB. Two-weapon fighting gives you an extra attack with your offhand weapon.

My question is how do you calculate this offhand attack? is it the best number in your Base Attack + penalties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The off-hand attack is a single attack at your full BAB.
You then need to factor in the penalties from 2-weapon-fighting (as explained [in the manual](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#twoWeaponFighting)).

For example, when fighting with an off-hand light weapon, a BAB of +9/+4, the 2WF feat and no other bonuses from abilities, magic, other feats or weapons, it would be +7/+2 from your main and +7 from your off-hand weapon.

Comment: The numbers you give are *including* the adjustments from the TWF feat; you should mention that.